# Converting UIImage to Data and back to UIImage differs in bytes (size)

Tags: swift, uikit, jpeg

I faced a problem, that converting the `UIImage` to `Data` and back to `UIImage` causes the last one to be larger [bytes].

Example (add to your device any photo which is larger than 3MB):

```
guard let image = UIImage(named: "image_larger_than_3MB"),
      let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
else { print("failure"); return }
print(data.count)

guard let imageBack = UIImage(data: data),
      let dataBack = imageBack.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
else { print("failure 2"); return }
print(dataBack.count)
```

In my case I receive the following console output:

```
5304493 // = 5,06 MB // size before conversion
5575422 // = 5,32 MB // size after conversion
```

So the initial image was of size 5,06 MB. Then I converted it to data with max quality. Then I convert it once again to image, and the size is larger, because it's 5,32 MB. The issue rises with the size of the image.

I understand that the issue is probably connected with compression used in the meantime. Anyway, it surprises me that the size is larger instead of smaller.

1. Is there any way to maintain the second `jpg` size same to the initial `jpg` image when using .jpeg compression..?
2. Why the size increased (I understand it could decrease)?

Comment: It the same if you convert jpg to bmp and back to jpg, isn't it? There is the same but you doesn't store bmp file on the disk.

Comment: Just keep the original data

Comment: If you want to keep the same size you would need to use a raw lossless format

Comment: I did stick to the original Data object to solve my problem. However, I asked because in theory I don't get it why the size increases. There is no new/more information saved to make it increase in size. From my understanding, it could decrease.